# How to build own android sdk and use across my apps?

Tags: android

Actually We've two apps.
Both the apps are almost same functionality.So, I want to reuse the code in both the apps by creating some common modules .
Can you please suggest the way?

Comment: you could import project as library

Comment: Create one library project and kept all common code (like interface etc.) which is used in both projects.

Answer (score 1):

Build one Project i.e. Project A and add modules in this project which are common to both projects

**1.**

> Now, when you create Project B and Project C which have same
>   funtionality, add Project A's JAR file in B and C. This way you will
>   able to re-use your code Project A

**2.**

> Another way is to create library Project A and include library to B
>   and C

I will recommend **1** to use because you will be reusing java code mostly which is implemented in Project A